# Identification of side-scrolling game

Tags: game-identification

In the blog [Fun with virtualization](http://virtuallyfun.superglobalmegacorp.com/2016/06/06/xkeropi-v0-65/) appears the following image:

[image: Screenshot of game running in emulator]
Does anybody know the game?

Comment: The blog post mentions it plays R-Type well enough, and the UI seems pretty similar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading through the blog post, I saw that he mentioned the x68000. Looked up the available games for it and R-Type is indeed on this system.

I found a video of it on youtube:

If you compare the image you provided with the video, you'll definitely notice that the colours are way of, but if you look at the UI, background, enemies and ship sprites, they appear to be very similar.

I'd say, this game is indeed **R-Type for the x68000**.